# Sort tags by most used in Laravel many to many polymorphic

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I'm working on a Laravel project and I need to implement tagging feature for multiple Eloquent models, so I chose many to many polymorphic relationship for this task. I need to show related tags and sort them by most used for particular model in sidebar section.

These models (tables) needs tagging feature, at the moment:

- Picture (id, filename, ...)
- Video (id, filename, ...)
- Article (id, slug, title, summary, content...)

And I made Tag model with taggables pivot table.

- Tag (id, name, description)
- taggables (id, tag_id, taggable_type, taggable_id)

All these models are connected via `morphToMany` with Tag model and Tag model via `morphedByMany` relations by convention, same way as in [Laravel 5.6 docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-polymorphic-relations) and all works fine.

This is taggables pivot schema:

```
<?php

class CreateTaggablesTable extends Migration {
    public function up() {
        Schema::create('taggables', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->unsignedInteger('tag_id');
            $table->morphs('taggable');
            $table->unique(['tag_id', 'taggable_type', 'taggable_id']); // Only unique
        });
    }
}
```

At the first moment, client requested just to show them on sidebar, so I done this:

```
<?php

namespace App; 
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Tag extends Model {
    public static function fetchLatest(int $limit) {
        return static::has('articles')->latest()->take($limit)->pluck('name');        
    }
}
```

After that client wanted to sort them by most used, so I decided to count somehow how many times they appear in taggables pivot table. I ended up with this:

```
<?php

namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Tag extends Model {
    public static function fetchByMostUsed(int $limit = 15, string $model = 'App\Article') 
    {
        return static::select('tags.id', 'tags.name')
            ->join('taggables', 'tags.id', '=', 'taggables.tag_id')
            ->selectRaw('count(taggables.tag_id) as aggregate')
            ->where('taggables.taggable_type', '=', $model)
            ->groupBy('tags.id', 'tags.name')
            ->orderBy('aggregate', 'desc')
            ->limit($limit)
           ->pluck('name');
   }
}
```

If you like more pure SQL query, its looks like:

```
select `tags`.`id`, `tags`.`name`, count(taggables.tag_id) as aggregate from `tags` inner join `taggables` on `tags`.`id` = `taggables`.`tag_id` where `taggables`.`taggable_type` = 'App\Article' and `tags`.`deleted_at` is null group by `tags`.`id`, `tags`.`name` order by `aggregate` desc limit 15
```

This works, but is there any easier, more elegant way to do this? At least, to get rid of fact that I need to hardcode or pass particular model (taggable_type) via variable? I would rather made 3 different methods (for each model than hardcode them anywhere in code.

Comment: Are you still looking for an answer?

Comment: Ofc. if you know how easier this can be done - sure. I am still maintain this project. I ended up with this by hardcoding which I dont like but what to do - I gave my best.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you can use `withCount()`: `Tag::withCount('articles')->orderByDesc('articles_count')->[...]`

Comment: Indeed. I will try it definitely. I cant remember right now if I already tried this and I if tried why I gave up using `withCount()`. Ty for the tip.

Answer (score -1):

`withCount('relationship')` adds a select for the additional column.

```
Article::withCount('tags')->orderBy('tags_count', 'desc')->get();
Picture::withCount('tags')->orderBy('tags_count', 'desc')->get();
Video::withCount('tags')->orderBy('tags_count', 'desc')->get();
```

Laravel Docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models

Comment: I think you misunderstood me. Indeed, your answer is correct, but I don't need to count them by retrieving certain model. I need to retrieve all tags associated with specific model type (taggable_type) and sort them by most used. "Most used" is actually determined by counting rows in taggables pivot table.
Imagine sidebar section where you looping all tag names (take a look on `fetchLatest` method above), but instead of sorting them by `latest()` you need to sort them by how many times they are used.